# typeahead not showing suggestions with bootstrap UI and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to display a static suggestions in a search textbox but nothing is displayed. I am following this https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv.
Here is my code.

HTML code:

```
 <div>    
    <input type="text" name="questions" id="questionss" class="form-control select2-search search_query" placeholder="what are you looking for ?" ng-model='myquery' typeahead="question for question in questions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:3" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">
          Get an answer ! <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button> 
    </div>
```

And my controller:

```
var Questions=["hello","hi","question1","question2","question2"];
$scope.questions=Questions;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if any error in  your browser console, as your code is really working.

**1.Make sure you have include all the dependence:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

**2.Notice `ng-app="angularTypeahead"` in the html and:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

**3.Notice `ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl"` and:**

```
myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope) {...});
```

**4.Full code:**

Here is a <kbd>**[full code live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEudub?p=preview)**</kbd>

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div ng-app="angularTypeahead">
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    
          <label for="states">Search for Answer</label>
          <input type="text" name="questions" id="questionss" class="form-control select2-search search_query" placeholder="what are you looking for ?" ng-model='myquery' typeahead="question for question in questions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:3">
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">
              Get an answer ! <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
    
    
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
    
    
        // setup controller and pass data source
        myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope) {
    
          var Questions = ["hello", "hi", "question1", "question2", "question2"];
          $scope.questions = Questions;
    
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: I have only one error related to bootstrap file error of analysing the value of <<top>> and error of analysing the value of <<left>>

Comment: So, what does the console say? post it here pls.

Comment: I have only this warning with chrome bindHtmlUnsafe is now deprecated. Use ngBindHtml instead and there no error but nothing is displaying and everything is okey should it be because of different version of bootstrap or angularjs. I am using bootstap ui 0.13.2 and angularjs v1.4.3 ? I have no idea why is not working

Comment: Why not create a code snippet and post your full codes?@desmanda

Comment: I tried bootstap ui 0.13.2 and angularjs v1.4.3 in the [full code plunder demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEudub?p=preview), it works although.

Comment: I have a big project I can't create a snippet but I have a doubt I had changed my input text style width=640px and in the brwoser there is  ng-style="display:block top:493.15px;  left:70px" for the ul concerned to display the list of suggestions could it be a problem ?? and the left and top are not working I guess because in firefox browser it said error in analysing the left and top !

Comment: bindHtmlUnsafe is now deprecated. Use ngBindHtml instead angular.js:12330:18 that is what I get in the console !

Comment: If it's broken by css. the html element structure would stay correct. So, just inspect your html, check if there is an `<ul>` exactly after your `<input>`,just like [this](http://imgur.com/PLFqBut). If yes, maybe css issue, if not, maybe js issue.

Comment: I just find out that it is a css issue.I am including a css class before the text input to make the form in the middle of the page .midd {
  margin-top: 50vh; 
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
} when I remove this class from the div the list of suggestions appears .I think the two properties left and top of the class dropdown-menu from bootstrap.css cannot be applied so nothing is showed. Thanks Yin